# Is node.js create one thread for one connection?

Tags: node.js

There are hundred clients are accessing nodejs server from different browser, how it's handle? will it open hundred http connection?

Comment: Yes, it will need multiple http connections. No, it wont spawn a new thread for each.

Comment: http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Comment: Node has one thread, it never has more.

Answer (score 2):

Node.JS does not open a new thread for every connection. This information is widely available on Google and the question has been asked a million times before you asked it.

Please read and understand the [select](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html) call before continuing any further research into this topic.

Comment: @user2564441 have you read up about the subject on the Internet yet? Can't hold your hand. You've got to do some of your own research.

Comment: I know that node.js is single thread, non blocking IO and event driven. I am planning to use node.js as a proxy server. Now users are hitting my apache server directly.Instead of that I am planning to put proxy server before the apche server.My assuption is if thousand requests are comming to the node.js server, it will not block the request and forward to apache server since it is an event driven.
My question is node.js server is going to hit the apache server for the result.Apache is multi thread and will wait prior request needs to finish. So how performance will be increase?